# How can I add up, then print, the values of two randomly generated numbers in Swift?

Tags: swift

As part of a Swift course, I created a very simple app that displays 2 dice and a button. Whenever the user presses the "roll dice" button, 2 random numbers are generated and then the corresponding dice images are shown.

What I want to do to improve on this little app is to add a label that sums the results of the two dice together and prints the results.

For example, if the user presses the "roll dice" button and one die shows the number 3, and other die shows the number 2, I want my label to display the sum of those two dice, which in this case is 5.

My code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!
    
    let diceArray = [
        UIImage(named: "DiceOne"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceTwo"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceThree"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceFour"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceFive"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceSix") ]
    
    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
 
        diceImageView1.image = diceArray[Int.random(in: 0...5)]
        diceImageView2.image = diceArray[Int.random(in: 0...5)]
    
    }
    
}
```

I honestly don't even know where to begin. Sorry, super beginner here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let x = Int.random(in: 1...6)
let y = Int.random(in: 1...6)
let z = x + y
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var combinedLabel: UILabel!

    let diceArray = [
        UIImage(named: "DiceOne"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceTwo"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceThree"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceFour"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceFive"),
        UIImage(named: "DiceSix")
    ]
    
    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let x = Int.random(in: 1...6)
        let y = Int.random(in: 1...6)
        let z = x + y
        diceImageView1.image = diceArray[x-1] // dice start counting at 1
        diceImageView2.image = diceArray[y-1] // array indices start at 0
        combinedLabel.text = "sum: \(z)"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so much for this. It worked like magic and it gave me a lot to study. I'm not saying I understand everything about it, since this is my 2nd week of learning Swift and Xcode but I have a general idea of what your code did. So basically the "let x" constant is creating a random number for the left dice and the "let y" is doing the same thing for the right side dice. so the line bellow that is changing the image properties to display the image based on the random number generated - 1, since the array starts counting from 0, right? Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a `UILabel` (e.g. called `sumLabel`) similar to your dice `UIImageView`s and then assign variables for each random number:

```
let firstRand = Int.random(in: 1...6)
let secondRand = Int.random(in: 1...6)
let sumRand = firstRand + secondRand
```

And then assign the result to the `sumLabel.text = sumRand` within `rollButtonPressed()`

Comment: Ahh yeah, great catch.